# Data Lost onresume after returning back from different activities

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume

I am a newbie on android programming and I think I came across a very basic problem. Actually searching stackoverflow for two days but I am not able to find a solution for my situation.
So in summary I am try to make an application for a calculation.
I have 5 activities: MainActivity, ActivityA (selecting something and taking value from ArrayList), ActivityB (again selecting something and taking value from ArrayList), ActivityC (entering value and than taking another value), Activity D (entering value and taking another value)
Then on Mainactivity these values will be used for an equation.

I take values by using intent and I coded  intent in onresume.
First I go to ActivityA and select what I want and return back to Mainactivity and I have the required value, but when I do this for ActivityB and return back to Mainactivity, I lost the value from ActivityA because I think program do the intent again for ActivityA also (this is the same for all other activities). So I think I need to somehow separate intent for all activities. I tried using sharedpreferences or creating same string on all activities with different values to use in a if or switch case in onresume part unfortunately I have not succeed it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Değerlerin girildiği text kutucuklarının tanımlanması
    EditText designPressure;
    EditText corrosionAllowance;
    EditText pipeDiameter;
    EditText selectedMaterial;
    EditText selectedAllowableStress;
    EditText selectedPipeClass;
    EditText selectedWeldFactor;
    EditText selectedTemperature;
    EditText selectedTempFactor;
    EditText selectedLocation;
    EditText selectedDesignFactor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Değerlerin girildiği textkutucuklarının eşleştirilmesi
        designPressure = findViewById(R.id.designPressure);
        corrosionAllowance = findViewById(R.id.corrosionAllowance);
        pipeDiameter = findViewById(R.id.pipeDiameter);
        selectedMaterial = findViewById(R.id.selectedMaterial);
        selectedAllowableStress = findViewById(R.id.selectedAllowableStress);
        selectedPipeClass = findViewById(R.id.selectedPipeClass);
        selectedWeldFactor = findViewById(R.id.selectedWeldFactor);
        selectedTemperature = findViewById(R.id.selectedTemperature);
        selectedTempFactor = findViewById(R.id.selectedTempFactor);
        selectedLocation = findViewById(R.id.selectedLocation);
        selectedDesignFactor = findViewById(R.id.selectedDesignFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){

        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Malzeme sayfasından bilgi alan kısım
        String selectedM = intent.getStringExtra("Material");
        selectedMaterial.setText(selectedM);
        String selectedAS = intent.getStringExtra("Allowable Stress");
        selectedAllowableStress.setText(selectedAS);

        //WeldFactor sayfasından bilgi alan kısım
        String weldFactors = intent.getStringExtra("Type");
        selectedPipeClass.setText(weldFactors);
        String eFactor = intent.getStringExtra("eFactor");
        selectedWeldFactor.setText(eFactor);
        // TempFactor sayfasından bilgi alan kısım
        String selectedTF = intent.getStringExtra("selectedTFactor");
        selectedTempFactor.setText(selectedTF);
        String selectedDT = intent.getStringExtra("selectedDTemp");
        selectedTemperature.setText(selectedDT);
        }

    //SelectMaterial tuşuna basınca MaterialList sayfasına giden toMAterialList onclick metodu
    public void toMaterialList(View view){

        Intent intentMaterial = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MaterialList.class);

        startActivity(intentMaterial);
    }

    //SelectWeldFactor tuşuna basınca WeldFactor sayfasına giden toWeldFactor onclick metodu
    public void toWeldFactor(View view){

        Intent intentWeldFactor = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WeldFactor.class);

        startActivity(intentWeldFactor);
    }

    //SelectTempFactor tuşuna basınca TempFactor sayfasına giden toTempFactor onclick metodu
    public void toTempFactor(View view){

        Intent intentTempFactor = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TempFactor.class);

        startActivity(intentTempFactor);
    }

    public void toDesignFactor(View view){

        Intent intentdesignFactor = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DesignFactor.class);

        startActivity(intentdesignFactor);
    }

    public void calculate(View view){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can not send data from activity B to activity A. if you want that you must use `startActivityForResult` .**you can not get data from an activity that is destroyed**.

The best way for you is using `sharedpreferences` .

//Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
       public static final String selectedMaterial = "selectedMaterial";
       public static final String selectedAllowableStress = "selectedAllowableStress";
       public static final String selectedTemperature = "selectedTemperature";
   // For get strings
      public static final String _selectedTemperature;
        public static final String _selectedAllowableStress;
       public static final String _selectedMaterial;

       SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
              sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      _selectedMaterial=editor.getString(selectedMaterial, "");
       _selectedAllowableStress=editor.getString(selectedAllowableStress, "");
                _selectedTemperature=editor.getString(selectedTemperature, "");
                editor.commit();
    
    }
    }
```

//Activity A

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
     public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
     public static final String selectedMaterial = "selectedMaterial";
    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    
      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
          editor.putString(selectedMaterial, "material");
          editor.commit();
    }
    }
```

//Activity B

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
     public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
     public static final String selectedMaterial = "selectedAllowableStress";
    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    
      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
          editor.putString(selectedAllowableStress, "allow");
          editor.commit();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am reviewing your code sample and try to understand, cause "static final string" part is new to me.

Comment: @Alienshow your welcome. "static final" is not important very much . you can remove that part.its just say that only one copy of variable exists which can't be reinitialize.

Comment: Thank you again. I see that I have tried shared preferences in a wrong way now it is ok.

Comment: @Alienshow Your welcome body . please accept the answer as the right answer.